# Windows Phone TextBox validation

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox

Does anyone know how I can check if there are any non alphabetical characters in a textbox?

If there are any symbols or numbers etc in the textbox - I want to do a:

`MessageBox.Show("Please enter only letters");`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at RegularExpressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Can you set the keyboard to only allow letters?

Answer (score 1):

In the textbox's KeyPress event, you can check if the character is a letter and cancel the keypress if it's not. This is untested, but should work.

```
private void YourTextbox_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only letters");
    }
}
```

Essentially you're testing if the character is a letter and, if it is, then allow the keypress to go through to the OS, otherwise cancel the keypress (by setting the `e.Handled` property to `true`).

Now, the user could bypass this by pasting in text that contains non-alphabetical characters, so it's more for a better user experience than security. To perform validation after the user has clicked on the submit button, you can use a iterate through the string to determine if there are any non-alphabetical characters. So, in your submit event, you could have something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < YourTextbox.Text.Length; i++)
{
    if(!char.IsLetter(YourTextbox.Text[i])
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only letters");
        break;
    }
}
```

[Char.IsLetter method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx).

Comment: You can also handle TextChanged to identify copy-pasting.